# Symfony 5 Many to Many with extra fields form builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I'm losing a lot of time on a (maybe) basic feature that everyone needs in his project.

The fact is that I'm stuck with form builder (a real daemon in this framework, I don't understand why it's so hard to use).

I got three entities :

`Recette`
`Ingredient`
`RecettesIngredients`

Both `Recette` and `Ingredient` do an One-To-Many with `RecettesIngredients`. It's a many-to-many with extra fields.

I've done a form builder `RecetteType` that does :

```
        ->add('recettesIngredients', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => RecettesIngredientsType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label' => 'XXX'
        ])
```

I've done a form builder (he works fine) `RecettesIngredientsType` that does :

```
        ->add('ingredients', EntityType::class, [
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => Ingredient::class,
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
```

When I try to render it:

```
{{ form_row(form.recettesIngredients) }}
```

*If I don't give an object to my form builder :*
I just got nothing to display but a blank page without error.

*If I give an object to my form builder :*
I have an error:

> "Unable to transform value for property path "ingredients": Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object."

If I remove the "multiple" option, I got a list of ingredients but without checkboxes to select them.

My question is simple :

How can I display a form in a Many-To-Many with extra field relation context properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made your exemple following the symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-add).
The Entities following your exemple:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecetteRepository::class)
 */
class Recette
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=RecetteIngredient::class, mappedBy="recette")
     *
     */
    private $ingredients;
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=IngredientRepository::class)
 */
class Ingredient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=RecetteIngredient::class, mappedBy="ingredient")
     */
    private $recette;
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecetteIngredientRepository::class)
 */
class RecetteIngredient
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Recette::class, inversedBy="ingredients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $recette;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Ingredient::class, inversedBy="recette")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ingredient;
```

My FormTypes are from your exemple.

I created two `Ingredient` in my DB

[image]

And made this controller code to test

```php
 $recette = new Recette();
 $recette->setName("Crèpes");

 $recetteIngredient = new RecetteIngredient();
 $recetteIngredient->setQuantity(5);
 $recette->addIngredient($recetteIngredient);

 $form = $this->createForm(RecetteType::class, $recette);

 return $this->render('demo.html.twig',['form'=>$form->createView()]);
```

The thing that I changed is the render. Since the number of `Ingredient` is dynamic, Symfony (and php server's code) has no idea the number of related entities you want to add or delete and you can not just do a `form_row()` on the collection type.

Here's my code grabed from the doc (I didn't changed html attributes name, it's just a demo.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    <ul id="email-fields-list"
        data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.ingredients.vars.prototype)|e }}"
        data-widget-tags="{{ '<li></li>'|e }}"
        data-widget-counter="{{ form.ingredients|length }}">
        {% for ingredient in form.ingredients %}
            <li>
                {{ form_errors(ingredient) }}
                {{ form_widget(ingredient) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <button type="button"
            class="add-another-collection-widget"
            data-list-selector="#email-fields-list">Add another ingredient</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.add-another-collection-widget').click(function (e) {
                var list = jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('data-list-selector'));
                // Try to find the counter of the list or use the length of the list
                var counter = list.data('widget-counter') || list.children().length;

                // grab the prototype template
                var newWidget = list.attr('data-prototype');
                // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
                // with a number that's unique to your emails
                // end name attribute looks like name="contact[emails][2]"
                newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, counter);
                // Increase the counter
                counter++;
                // And store it, the length cannot be used if deleting widgets is allowed
                list.data('widget-counter', counter);

                // create a new list element and add it to the list
                var newElem = jQuery(list.attr('data-widget-tags')).html(newWidget);
                newElem.appendTo(list);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: First of all, i really want to thank you for this amazing help.
It works perfectly !

What a big story to render a ManyToMany with extra attribute field :P

Comment: The goal is understanding why you need js to to that.

Comment: Is there anyway to add a "delete ingredient" (from recipe) button to each ingredient bloc ?

Comment: It's all in the doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed