# How to create a form with quantities linked with an EntityType field in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to recover some product and add a quantity field to the side for each of them.
All of this, in a promo code's formular.

PromoCode formular without product/quantity form row:
[image: PromoCode formular without product/quantity form row]

```
class CodePromoType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder->add('montantMinimum', MoneyType::class, [
        'label' => 'Montant minimum en € requis pour appliquer la promotion',
        'attr' => ['placeholder' => '10']
    ])
            ->add('montant', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Montant en € ou %',
        'attr' => ['placeholder' => '10']
    ])
            ->add('DLC', DateType::class, [
        'label' => 'Date limite de consomation',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ])
            ->add('fraisDePortOfferts', CheckboxType::class, [
        'label' => 'Frais de port offert',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ])
            ->add('typePromo', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => 'Type de promotion',
        'choices' => [
            'Euro €' => 'e',
            'Pourcentage %' => 'p',
        ],
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => CodePromo::class,
        'allow_extra_fields' => true
    ]);
}
}
```

I'm using the products's relation (oneToMany) in my PromoCode class to create my form with the form builder.

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CodePromoRepository::class)]
class CodePromo
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 20)]
private $code;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
private $DLC;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
private $dateC;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
private $montant;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 1)]
private $typePromo;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
private $montantMinimum;

#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'codePromo', targetEntity: ProduitCodePromo::class)]
private $produits;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
private $fraisDePortOfferts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->produits = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getCode(): ?string
{
    return $this->code;
}

public function setCode(string $code): self
{
    $this->code = $code;

    return $this;
}

public function getDLC(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->DLC;
}

public function setDLC(\DateTimeInterface $DLC): self
{
    $this->DLC = $DLC;

    return $this;
}

public function getDateC(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->dateC;
}

public function setDateC(\DateTimeInterface $dateC): self
{
    $this->dateC = $dateC;

    return $this;
}

public function getMontant(): ?float
{
    return $this->montant;
}

public function setMontant(float $montant): self
{
    $this->montant = $montant;

    return $this;
}

public function getTypePromo(): ?string
{
    return $this->typePromo;
}

public function setTypePromo(string $typePromo): self
{
    $this->typePromo = $typePromo;

    return $this;
}

public function getMontantMinimum(): ?float
{
    return $this->montantMinimum;
}

public function setMontantMinimum(float $montantMinimum): self
{
    $this->montantMinimum = $montantMinimum;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection<int, ProduitCodePromo>
 */
public function getProduit(): Collection
{
    return $this->produits;
}

public function addProduit(ProduitCodePromo $produits): self
{
    if (!$this->produits->contains($produits)) {
        $this->produits[] = $produits;
        $produits->setCodePromo($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeProduit(ProduitCodePromo $produits): self
{
    if ($this->produits->removeElement($produits)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($produits->getCodePromo() === $this) {
            $produits->setCodePromo(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getFraisDePortOfferts(): ?bool
{
    return $this->fraisDePortOfferts;
}

public function setFraisDePortOfferts(bool $fraisDePortOfferts): self
{
    $this->fraisDePortOfferts = $fraisDePortOfferts;

    return $this;
}
}
```

This is the table linked with PromoCode, as u can see, I want to use this quantity field.

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProduitCodePromoRepository::class)]
class ProduitCodePromo
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Produit::class, inversedBy: 'produitsCodePromo')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $produit;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: CodePromo::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $codePromo;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $quantite;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getProduit(): ?Produit
{
    return $this->produit;
}

public function setProduit(?Produit $produit): self
{
    $this->produit = $produit;

    return $this;
}

public function getCodePromo(): ?CodePromo
{
    return $this->codePromo;
}

public function setCodePromo(?CodePromo $codePromo): self
{
    $this->codePromo = $codePromo;

    return $this;
}

public function getQuantite(): ?int
{
    return $this->quantite;
}

public function setQuantite(int $quantite): self
{
    $this->quantite = $quantite;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new `FormType` for your `ProduitCodePromo` entity and add it to your base form. You'll have to also add a `product` field in your new formType.

The way it should be added is described in a lot of other answers here. In that case you'll have to use the `CollectionType`. You'll find an (with ManyToMany relationship) exemple here  [Symfony 5 Many to Many with extra fields form builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782701/symfony-5-many-to-many-with-extra-fields-form-builder/68845319#68845319)